# A strange virtualenv issue-- even with -p it installs multiple pythons

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a virtual environment with 3.4. I have followed instructions found through searching stackoverflow, as well as posting this issue on reddit, and continue to have the same problem: even when I specify python3.4, it installs both 3.4 AND 2.7. This then leads to all of the problems I was trying to avoid by using a virtual environment in the first place.

```
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 venv
(various output saying it's creating venv/bin/python with 3.4)
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

when I look in the venv/bin folder it has binaries for both 2.7.9 and 3.4.

after activating the environment:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/theinevitable/Documents/python/test/venv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin

$ which python
/Users/theinevitable/Documents/python/test/venv/bin/python
$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
```

one person on reddit suggested trying to use venv instead:

```
$ python3.4 -m venv my_venv
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4: No module named venv

$ pyvenv tester
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pyvenv", line 10
    print('Error: %s' % e, file=sys.stderr)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I would suggest using `pyvenv` instead of `virtualenv` with `Python 3 `, for more info check https://robinwinslow.co.uk/2013/12/26/python-3-4-virtual-environment/

Comment: @dm295 I also tried pyvenv, it gives me an error message: 

`File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pyvenv-3.4", line 10
        print('Error: %s' % e, file=sys.stderr)
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @dm295 Re-downloaded 3.4 and tried again, pyvenv finally worked. Thanks!